# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: controllers/web.php
>
> Line Number: 181

When I open the latest post on my website.

This the code from `detail.php`:

```
            <?php
                // ...
                $p_satu = explode(' ',$c['tanggal']);
                $tgl = explode('-',$p_satu[0]); 
                $bulan = array('Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun','Jul','Ags','Sep','Okt', 'Nov','D');
            ?>
            <p><?php echo $tgl[2]; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $bulan[($tgl[1]-1)]; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this `web.php`:

```
<?php
// ...
private function cookiesetter($kode = 0){
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$kode])){
        $content = $this->blog_model->GetContent("where kode_content = '$kode'")->result_array();
        $result = $this->blog_model->UpdateData('content',array('counter' => ($content[0]['counter'])),array('kode_content'=>$kode));
        if($result == 1){
            setcookie($kode,"http://xxx.example.com", time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess. Update your `controllers/web.php`

```
$result = 0;
if (!empty($content[0])) {
    $result = $this->blog_model->UpdateData('content',array('counter' => ($content[0]['counter'])),array('kode_content'=>$kode));
}
if ($result == 1) { 
    .....
}
```

If this doesn't fixed your error, let me know the code from this `Line Number: 181 controllers/web.php`

Answer (score 0):

So your array tgl does not have the index 2. You have to check what value you are getting in $p_satu[0]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in `array` accessing and is thrown by having an `undefined offset` in an array, or rather by accessing a `key=>value` pair in an array that does not exist. For example:

```
$array = array(
    1=> 'hi',
    3 => 'bye'
);
echo $array[0]; //Throws the error undefined offset since '0' is not an index in the array
```

To debug, I'd recommend doing a `print_r()` or `var_dump` on the array you are accessing with index `[0]` and seeing what the contents of the array are as they are likely not what you expect.